# Open regular app instead of app clip if downloaded

Tags: ios, swift, apple-appclips

I'm currently working on creating an app that will have an app clip available for people who don't have it downloaded.

The way I'm looking at opening the app is by having a user scan a QR code that will have a query at the end of it to specify what QR code they scanned. I'm just wondering if the user has the app downloaded, will it open the app clip instead of the actual app? I'm very new to this and all the documentation is a bit confusing. Thanks!